# jQuery implement a destroy method on a custom plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, destroy, jquery-events

I am working on a plugin for an internal tool that keeps track of how long it takes to work on specific tasks. I am presenting a visual reference of the time its taken but using the timestamps in the database to capture to true values.

In the plugin I am working on, I am trying to build a destroy function that resets the counter back to zero.

How I did this was just destroyed the original element that this plugin was initiated on. I figured this would then allow the garbage collector to clean up anything else.

The reason I don't think this is working is because I added in a line that updates the `document title` as the time progresses. When I "Destroy" it, the title acts all funky like the timer is still going even though the actual timer I started this on was reset like I expected.

How can I tell if this is being destroyed correctly?

http://jsfiddle.net/9bf4jmao/3/

```
// BEGIN THE PLUGIN
var globalContainer;
(function($) {

$.fn.upCount = function(options, callback) {
    var settings = $.extend({
        startTime: null,
        offset: null,
        reset: null,
        resume: null
    }, options);

    // Save container
    var container = this;
    globalContainer = container.parent().html();

    // get the current date
    var currentDate = function() {
        // get client's current date
        var date = new Date();

        // turn date to utc
        var utc = date.getTime() + (date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);

        // set new Date object
        var new_date = new Date(utc + (3600000 * settings.offset))

        return new_date;
    };

    // Define some global vars
    var original_date = currentDate();
    var target_date = new Date('12/31/2020 12:00:00'); // Count up to this date

    // Are we resetting our counter?
    if(settings.reset){
        reset();
    }

    // Do we need to start our counter at a certain time if we left and came back?
    if(settings.startTime){
        resumeTimer(new Date(settings.startTime));
    }

    // Reset the counter by destroying the element it was bound to
    function reset() {
        var timerContainer = $('[name=timerContainer]');
        timerContainer.empty().append(globalContainer).find('.time').empty().append('00');
    }

    // Given a start time, lets set the timer
    function resumeTimer(startTime){
       original_date = startTime;
    }

    // Start the counter
    function countUp() {

        // Set our current date
        var current_date = currentDate(); 

        // difference of dates
        var difference = current_date - original_date;
        //console.log(original_date)

        if (current_date >= target_date) {
            // stop timer
            clearInterval(interval);
            if (callback && typeof callback === 'function') callback();
            return;
        }

        // basic math variables
        var _second = 1000,
            _minute = _second * 60,
            _hour = _minute * 60,
            _day = _hour * 24;

        // calculate dates
        var days = Math.floor(difference / _day),
            hours = Math.floor((difference % _day) / _hour),
            minutes = Math.floor((difference % _hour) / _minute),
            seconds = Math.floor((difference % _minute) / _second);

        // fix dates so that it will show two digets
        days = (String(days).length >= 2) ? days : '0' + days;
        hours = (String(hours).length >= 2) ? hours : '0' + hours;
        minutes = (String(minutes).length >= 2) ? minutes : '0' + minutes;
        seconds = (String(seconds).length >= 2) ? seconds : '0' + seconds;

        // based on the date change the refrence wording
        var ref_days = (days === 1) ? 'day' : 'days',
            ref_hours = (hours === 1) ? 'hour' : 'hours',
            ref_minutes = (minutes === 1) ? 'minute' : 'minutes',
            ref_seconds = (seconds === 1) ? 'second' : 'seconds';

        // set to DOM
        container.find('.days').text(days);
        container.find('.hours').text(hours);
        container.find('.minutes').text(minutes);
        container.find('.seconds').text(seconds);

        container.find('.days_ref').text(ref_days);
        container.find('.hours_ref').text(ref_hours);
        container.find('.minutes_ref').text(ref_minutes);
        container.find('.seconds_ref').text(ref_seconds);

        // Update our title
        document.title = 'Task Tracker - ' + days +'.'+hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds;
    };

    // start
    interval = setInterval(countUp, 1000);
};

})(jQuery);
 // END THE PLUGIN
```

What I am doing is calling `$('.countdown').upCount({reset:true});` in order to destroy (or what I thought destroyed it)

**UPDATE**
I updated the fiddle to show that even after the plugin is "destroyed" the element is continued to be updated which is an indication that something wasn't done as it should have been.

**UPDATE 2**
When I brought up this question in chat, I was told that I `interval = setInterval(...) but scope block it`.

I wasn't too sure what to make of that and couldn't really get an answer from then on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best guess is that I don't see you clearing your interval:

```
// in your reset function, you should be stopping the interval:
clearInterval(interval);
```

However, you need to initialize that variable at the top of your script, which I don't see.

```
// top of your script. 
var interval;
```

Comment: I did in fact try giving `interval` a global scope and then cleared it within the reset function. The timer reset and continued to count.

Comment: Heres the fiddle of your suggestion. http://jsfiddle.net/9bf4jmao/15/ It continues to count up even after the interval is reset

Comment: As a test, I removed the part that re-appended the cloned element and just let it empty the parent container. This resulted in the timer continuing to count up even though I didn't replace the original element.

Comment: As far as you tracking a total time vs resetting the time, I imagine you'll want to store the accruing values inside a dataset of the element. Otherwise they'll reset to 0 every time you call countUp(). Not part of your issue, but that's why the timer tracker resets when starting a new task.

Comment: As far as tracking the time, I already took care of that. The code provided was just to get the basic issue resolved. It appears that you also added `return` in the `if(settings.reset){return reset();}` which I had not tried. Could you explain why that was needed vs `if` statement calling the function that stopped it?

Comment: The return causes the script to stop at that point, this keeps the interval from being reinstated at the bottom of your plugin.

Comment: I'd also advise moving your global variables into a namespaced dataset on the element to avoid polluting the global namespace. I realize the script provided is the basic rudimentary version but if you hadn't considered it, I recommend it.

Comment: This appears to be working for me; can't believe it was the simple. I am going to integrate the change into my project shortly and if all goes well I will accept this answer. Thank you for your time and suggestions!

Comment: @mindfullscience - This appears to be working fine in my application. Could you possibly explain a little more about moving the global vars? Where exactly would I put them?

Comment: Luckily jQuery makes this pretty easy. You can store the variables as data to the element itself via `$(container).data('timer', interval)`. To access the variable, use `$(container).data('timer')`. That will return the value stored. See here for more info on that: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/